# Using org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer

Tags: geoserver

We have a GIS application to view Map(like Google) developed in Java, using PostgreSQL DB & GeoServer/OpenLayers as backend. This application is deployed on OpenShift post which users started complaining about the slowness of the application.

So, to understand the slowness , we have enabled Dynatrace post which we noticed 90% of code execution time is being taken by the below thread for calls having high response time-

```
-Java | org.geotools.renderer.lite.StreamingRenderer$PainterThread 
(Overall call duration 43 secs, StreamingRenderer$PainterThread 42 secs)
```

Is there a way to get the source code?
How can the execution time of this thread can be improved. What are the factors involved?

Oo can any configurations to be changed at GeoServer level?

Comment: All the code is on github

Comment: We'd need to see more about your data and styles to be able to say more about rendering speed